# Show that $G/H\cong H\backslash G$.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ a group and $H\lhd G$. I wanted to define \begin{align*}\varphi:G/H&\longrightarrow H\backslash G\\ gH&\longmapsto  Hg\end{align*}

and show that it's an isomorphism (what looked obvious to me since $$\varphi(gH)=\varphi(g'H)\implies Hg=Hg'\implies g=g'$$
what prove the injectivity. The surjectivity is obvious since if $Hg\in H\backslash G$, then $\varphi(gH)=Hg$). But my teacher said it doesn't work and that I have to prove that
\begin{align*}\psi:G/H&\longrightarrow H\backslash G\\ gH&\longmapsto  Hg^{-1}\end{align*}

but I don't understand why my application $\varphi$ doesn't work. Any idea ?

Comment: The question is, what group structure do you put on $H\backslash G$ ? Because as a set it is equal to $G/H$, and your $\varphi$ is the identity.

Comment: @sigmabe: To me $$\psi(g_1g_2H)=H(g_1g_2)^{-1}=Hg_2^{-1}g_1^{-1}=Hg_2^{-1}Hg_{1}^{-1}H=\psi(g_2)\psi(g_2)\neq \varphi(g_1)\psi(g_2),$$ whereas $$\varphi(g_1g_2H)=Hg_1g_2=Hg_1Hg_2=\varphi(g_1)\varphi(g_2)$$ and this is an homomorphism. Where am I wrong ?